# The modulo parity party

Tags: code-golf, array, number-theory

You are given an array **A** of **n** strictly positive integers, with **n ≥ 2**.

Your task is to map each entry **A<sub>i</sub>** to:

- **1** if **A<sub>j</sub> mod A<sub>i</sub>** is odd for each **j** such that **1 ≤ j ≤ n** and **j ≠ i**
- **2** if **A<sub>j</sub> mod A<sub>i</sub>** is even for each **j** such that **1 ≤ j ≤ n** and **j ≠ i**
- **0** otherwise (mixed parities)

### Example

For **A = [ 73, 50, 61 ]**, we have:

- 50 mod 73 = **50**, 61 mod 73 = **61** → mixed
- 73 mod 50 = **23**, 61 mod 50 = **11** → all odd
- 73 mod 61 = **12**, 50 mod 61 = **50** → all even

Therefore, the expected output is **[ 0, 1, 2 ]**.

### Rules

- You may use any three distinct values (of any type) instead of **0**, **1** and **2** as long as they're consistent. *Please specify your mapping* if you're not using the one described in the challenge.
- Should there be any doubt about that, [zero is even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

### Test cases

```
[ 1, 2 ] --> [ 2, 1 ]
[ 3, 4 ] --> [ 1, 1 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ] --> [ 2, 1, 0 ]
[ 4, 4, 4 ] --> [ 2, 2, 2 ]
[ 73, 50, 61 ] --> [ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 941, 459, 533 ] --> [ 1, 0, 0 ]
[ 817, 19, 928, 177 ] --> [ 1, 2, 1, 1 ]
[ 312, 463, 336, 729, 513 ] --> [ 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 53, 47, 33, 87, 81, 3, 17 ] --> [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0 ]
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118505/58563)

Comment: Do the output values have to be integers or would `[1]`, `[0, 1]`, and `[1, 1]` work?

Comment: @Dennis Any consistent values are fine. So yes, that would work!

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to ovs</sup>

```python
x=input()
for j in x:k=sum(i%j%2for i in x);print(k<len(x)-1)+0**k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchLDkAwFEDRuVW8iaSlEvUJ8VmJGBJPeRoqqdVXGZ2bqx@zHJQ5Z3skfRvGg/k4YQUksI3qr3tnGK5h9l38L2/1iWSY6raJmOWJ5HEaRcq5AcpcQFEJyL21t5a@BcgKxhc)

Returns `1,0,2` instead `0,1,2`.

Comment: replace `(k<1)` with `0**k` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
%þœ-€0Ḃ‘Ṭ
```

Returns **[1, 1], [0, 1], [1]** instead of **0, 1, 2**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU67DcJADO2Zwg2dkeLzfUdBUUoalAXoUBp6aDJEBiANTZRBLoscdqSLZMnvPfs9@37r@0cp5@W3fi7bMDX5O2zPMc9TWV7C13eeR@nXUtoTQAuEYKDDHTOCrVh1BK7U4l6VBll1DYKnqiQrDuuS6Hy4IgUEEi2ZKCCE4xJJuPWSwuwRglEfHT6nnwQdIkTpUbJZA3Sh@wM)

#### How it works

```
%þœ-€0Ḃ‘Ṭ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

%þ           Build the modulus table.
  œ-€0       Remove one 0 from each list of moduli.
      Ḃ      Take the last bit of each.
       ‘     Increment, mapping 0 and 1 to 1 and 2.
        Ṭ    Untruth; map each array to an aray of 1's at the specified indices.
             This yields:
                 [1] if the array contains only 1's (all even).
                 [0, 1] if the array contains only 2's (all odd).
                 [1, 1] if the array contains 1's and 2's.
```

Comment: Could you replace `‘ṬUḄ` with `Q€Ḅ` to save a byte?

Comment: Sadly, no. `Q€` could return `[0, 1]` or `[1, 0]`.

Comment: Oh, right. I think `[1]`, `[1,1]`, and `[0,1]` are three distinct values so `%þœ-€0Ḃ‘Ṭ` should be acceptable for 9. EDIT - ah I see you asked this exact question :)

Comment: Another 9 byte alternative is ``¹-Ƥ%"%2‘Ṭ``

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
!G\o~tAws1=-
```

This uses `0`, `-1`, `1` instead of `0`, `1`, `2` respectively.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9E9Jr@uxLG82NBW9///aAVTYx0FE3MdBWMgbQGkLQyBbB0FQ3OFWAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY0xCwIxDIV3f8Vzj2CatmkHB8HpZgfhPNBdcfDgNv96TVoI9OXlfa/v5/pqj3ab9tP981vP25dPh3a5thlMCFh2M4QQu3CHIF1H6tO1WiIdCZn7WqMFY6pmyggXVgKbUUMxoTp62dpiNlgkEzQ4wYNI/qn6hVDsLVYpjmL5Aw).

#### Explanation

```
!    % Implicit input: row vector. Transpose into a column
G    % Push input again
\    % Modulus, element-wise with broadcast. Gives a square matrix
o    % Parity: gives 1 for odd, 0 for even
~    % Logical negate: 0 for odd, 1 for even
t    % Duplicate
A    % All: gives 1 for columns that contain only 1
w    % Swap
s    % Sum of each column
1    % Push 1
=    % Is equal? Gives 1 if the column sum was 1, 0 otherwise
-    % Subtract, element-wise. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>118</s> <s>114</s> <s>97</s> <s>92</s> <s>91</s> 86 bytes

- Thanks to [Peter Cordes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30206/peter-cordes) for bugfixing.
- Saved <s>four</s> twenty-one bytes thanks to [Peter Cordes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30206/peter-cordes); suggesting to use a different output value mapping; `[0 1 2] ~ [3 2 1]`.
- Saved five bytes; using yet another mapping; `[0 1 2] ~ [  ]`.
- Saved a byte; golfed `for(i=0;i<n;i++,putchar...` to `for(i=~0;++i<n;putchar...`.
- Saved five bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
i,j,r;f(A,n)int*A;{for(i=~0;++i<n;putchar(r))for(r=0,j=n;j--;)r|=j-i?A[j]%A[i]%2+1:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdLdaoMwFAfw6@0pDoWCWY9gEm3sUjfsd59BvChCN4W54bqrrnt1l491rI1ODhjw8Mv/JBb@U1G0bYkVNnLvpViTsj7cpfK4f228MvkK5GhUTmv59nEonneN1xCivzRJgFVSy8r3JWk@k8ovH9OsyodpVuZDNqL3gTy1L7uy9sjx9kaZkGZ5cgSKwKDzOZn9GdFbvXsDmPoPkAFDoJAPrnqJtObMmBwh7Ddnjkn/Nee/ORF4jzlH3pETIbhiz@bCmCGa6jEXXaauHnNpTKGGjwKEMe0yl44ZoL2CbnNlzEmoWsJoomTOHXPlmHrw/tnXxoypUDsrcsJitRDiwlxj6Jr2SC9u6mxu7L1T1RKO1QlwPkYQTCem/MfcYOTOzmzUv2nP5taYkf6ZhBYRYvWOVQSuAxtzi8I1bdlDYFZW5qn9Bg)

Comment: Your test functions on TIO don't pass enough args, and this undefined behaviour leads to a division by zero (SIGFPE) from the last test case.  `f(I,7)` overwrites the first element of `I[]` (`A[]` in f()) with one of the args that you're using as locals.  `f()` assumes that arg was passed on the stack by the caller, but the caller didn't know that, and what's actually on the stack above the return address is `A[0]`.  (i.e. this UB caused `t` and `A[0]` to have the same address).  Anyway, this is only UB in your *test function* on TIO.

Comment: And BTW, I couldn't repro the crash locally so I had to add `execlp("/usr/bin/objdump", "objdump", "-drwC", "-Mintel", argv[0], 0);` to main to get the asm from TIO's gcc 7.2.1, which didn't exactly match my Arch Linux gcc 7.2.1.  After turning that disassembly back into asm source for the calling function, I could repro it locally inside gdb and confirm exactly what was happening.

Comment: You might save bytes using a different mapping, like 1 for even, 2 for odd, 3 for mixed, so you can `o|=1<<(A[j]%A[i]%2)` without needing any fancy decoding for `o`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for noting, even though I still do not fully understand why the first array entry gets overwritten. I now chose to use global variables instead of local ones, removing the undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PeterCordes I also took your golfing suggestion and managed to save four bytes. However, I do not know if this really was what you were suggesting, as you wrote `o|=1<<...` instead of something along the lines of `o|=1<<(t=...`.

Comment: The question says you can choose your own number codes.  1 -> even, 2 -> odd, 3 -> mixed makes it a bitmap where you can just `r|=1<<...`, like this: `i,j,r;f(A,n)int*A;{for(i=0;i<n;i++){for(j=r=0;j<n;j++)j-i&&(r|=1<<A[j]%A[i]%2);printf("%d,",r);}}` 97 bytes.  Working on an x86 asm answer using `idiv` / `and edx,1` / `bts edi, edx` to do the same thing.

Comment: And BTW, your original didn't have a bug in the strictest sense, just a requirement on the caller to pass additional args (so you could argue it was your test `main()` that was buggy).  But yeah, globals work too, without costing any extra bytes.  Up to 6 integer args is safe when targeting the x86-64 System V ABI, because those will be register args, not stack.  But it's still better to avoid UB in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the golf; did not really understand your suggestion to the fullest. Did not know that on x86-64 the problem only comes when using six function parameters, glad to know now! If not a bug, it would probably violate at least partially the allowed I/O format, as the only input is an array (and array length in languages like C).

Comment: @ceilingcat Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>57</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
(s=#;And@@#.Or@@#&@OddQ@Rest@Sort[s~Mod~#]&)/@#&
```

This returns:

- `False.True` for **0** (mixed)
- `True.True` for **1** (all odd)
- `False.False` for **2** (all even)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X6PYVtnaMS/FwUFZz78ISKo5@KekBDoEpRaXOATnF5VEF9f55qfUKceqaeoDZf@nOVSbGusomJjrKBgDaQsgbWEIZOsoGJrX/v@vW1CUmVcCAA)

Here's a slightly longer alternative (49 bytes):

```
Sign[(s=#;Tr@Mod[s~Mod~#,2]&)/@#/.Tr[1^#]-1->-1]&
```

This one returns:

- `1` for **0** (mixed)
- `-1` for **1** (all odd)
- `0` for **2** (all even)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PzgzPS9ao9hW2TqkyME3PyW6uA5I1inrGMWqaeo7KOvrhRRFG8Ypx@oa6trpGsaq/U9zqDY11lEwMddRMAbSFkDawhDI1lEwNK/9/1@3oCgzrwQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 101 bytes

```
g: func[b][foreach n b[a: copy[]foreach m b[append a m % n % 2]sort a a: copy next a print unique a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY47DoMwEER7TjENfZY1GDhGWssFH0MoYogDUnJ6sigfQcp5b2a1wbXr2bUwdu1LdItvTG1NNwZXNRd41KYq0YzT09gvvG5wmpxvUUmIpRUjsfcxzAI@dXj32OIUBj9j8cNtcaisXd@ghyHZRL/EUBaI9ha88wrqr6EZ6QkZ2R0rFEGlBVLmQzcnDSpQJDlI64NiSqAyBnMGnciUjtNUPtNikWvkBJYD4tcX)

Returns `1 0` for mixed, `1` for odd and `0` for even

```
g: func[b] [
    foreach n b [
        a: copy []
        foreach m b [
            append a m % n % 2
        ]
        sort a
        a: copy next a
        print unique a
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```
a=>a.map(A=>a.map(B=>d+=B%A%2,d=0)|!a[d+1]-!d)
```

Returns -1 (even), 1 (odd), and 0 (mixed).

**How it works:**

The `d` accumulator will be:

1. Zero if all even moduli.  (`!a[d+1]` == false, `!d` == 1, `false - 1` == **-1**)
2. One less <sup>*</sup>  than the length of the array if all odd moduli.  ( <sup>*</sup> The accumulator includes an element modulused against itself, resulting in *one* even modulus.)  (`!a[d+1]` == true, `!d` == 0, `true - 0` == **1**)
3. Two or more less than the length of the array if a mix.  (`!a[d+1]` == false, `!d` == 0, `false - 0` == **0**)

**Test cases:**

```js
let f=

a=>a.map(A=>a.map(B=>d+=B%A%2,d=0)|!a[d+1]-!d)

console.log(f([ 1, 2 ] ) + ''); // [ -1, 1 ]
console.log(f([ 3, 4 ] ) + ''); // [ 1, 1 ]
console.log(f([ 1, 2, 3 ] ) + ''); // [ -1, 1, 0 ]
console.log(f([ 4, 4, 4 ] ) + ''); // [ -1, -1, -1 ]
console.log(f([ 73, 50, 61 ] ) + ''); // [ 0, 1, -1 ]
console.log(f([ 941, 459, 533 ] ) + ''); // [ 1, 0, 0 ]
console.log(f([ 817, 19, 928, 177 ] ) + ''); // [ 1, -1, 1, 1 ]
console.log(f([ 312, 463, 336, 729, 513 ] ) + ''); // [ 0, -1, 0, 0, 0 ]
console.log(f([ 53, 47, 33, 87, 81, 3, 17 ] ) + ''); // [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>27</strike> 20 bytes

```
[:<@~.@}:@\:"1~2||/~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCsJAEET7fMWQJgh6Zm/vbnOHwoFgZWWrnRiCjT8Q8@vnYpFEli3eDjM7r1KbpscxocEWLZLuzuB0vZzLLR3yZPIn5XuqabLjuJ/KpkL1fAxv9CBYzMBw@FN4QfebGYXhWwRaLtERnI/wvHJ1JKCIaDuQyOoTWbjAYA4QqyZambz2EJXQiQZoCQ1B@QI)

Uses [1 0] [1] [0] instead of 0 1 2

### Explanation:

`|/~` - makes a table with remainders:

```
  |/~ 73 50 61 
 0 50 61
23  0 11
12 50  0
```

`2|` odd or even? :

```
   2||/~ 73 50 61 
0 0 1
1 0 1
0 0 0
```

`<@~.@}:@\:"1` - sort down, drop last element (always a zero), keep the ùnique elements and box each row:

```
   <@~.@}:@\:"1~2||/~ 73 50 61 
┌───┬─┬─┐
│1 0│1│0│
└───┴─┴─┘
```

Comment: 16 bytes with ``2/:~@:|"1]|1]\.]`` returning a list of pairs.

Comment: @ miles Thank you! Is this output acceptable?

Comment: Actually no, I missed that part about distinct values. I'll get back to it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```ruby
->r{r.map{m=r.shift;s=r.map{|e|e%m%2}.uniq.sort;r<<m;s}}
```

Returns **[0, 1], [1], [0]** instead of **0, 1, 2** (i.e. **[0]** for all even , **[1]** for all odd, and **[0, 1]** for mixed).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU8xjoMwEOx5xYoonbECNhhEyCOuRS5yh1EogMQ2pzuB307WMkq1M7Mzs1q9fP/vfbMnN71qOt6f69hoah5Db2vTBGVTmzqP58zRZRpe1Mza1vp6HWvj3P5crIH4S9lFTwbai4R@1qB@1USgTQObuw7JhcDBx@FPdXHURoAWApkkHjECPCCvEWCBcJQ/G4GmHIuKNPCKo5fnFars8JepwEOoVFmJQIijPcVKXmCesYKAyHwmPTK5vy38ikCJs8RW5sMyklTdfx6wbnaD8OtptQ6S5AantW@tdLHb3w)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>71</s> 69 + 1 (`-a`) = 70 bytes

```perl
map{//;$j=$s='';$j++-$i&&($s+=$_%$'&1)for@F;say$s?0|$s==$#F:2;$i++}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBCgIhFEDRXxF6aaE22iQzJNKs3PUN4aLAqJR5baL69V6u7lncep5vjuie6rvrPFwDYBCiQUoNmfMVoAxwWoLgdn0p8xQ9phfgwXzaGWAR91sPWcrvFIlcr9huUKxvHVtH26yYHX6lPnN5IOmj2xhrSKc/)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 38 bytes

Includes `+3` for `-p`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/\d+/$@|=$_%$&%2+1for<$`$'>;$@/gee
```

Outputs 1 for all even, 2 for all odd, 3 for mixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>95</s> <s>65</s> 63 bytes

```
import StdEnv
```

```
\l=[sum(removeDup[-1^(j rem i)\\j<-l|j<>i])\\i<-l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoMwFIXh3ae40MWCDmKLDtrJDoVujomFEGOJ5EbRRCj02Xt7p/98w9HOKE@4jNEZQGU9WVyXLUAfxrs/qA9qC8kJJmhBulbsEdPN4HKYLq4iL17pDGywZynnJnffubnZgWEZQ9LyUcC1zOBSZVBya25d8M6gqGCgn56ceu@UP57UfbxCq/c/)

As a lambda, taking `[Int]` and returning `[Int]`, mapping to:

- `0`: mixed
- `1`: all even
- `-1`: all odd

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>91</s> 89 bytes

```java
a->{for(int z:a){int s=1;for(int y:a)s+=y%z%2;System.out.print(" "+(s<a.length)+(s<2));}}
```

- Using `truetrue` instead of `2` for even
- Using `falsefalse` instead of `1` for odd
- Using `truefalse` instead of `0` for mixed

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lZJBboMwEEX3PcUoUiRQJqjGgKGU3qDZZFl14RKSkhKDsJMqQZydDoQu2p0lW/J8@89/sn2UF7mum0Idd19DXkmt4VWWqnsAKJUp2r3MC9iMJcClLneQO6S/vYN0UxJ7mjS0kabMYQMKMhjk@qXb1@14EG5P0u3Ghc5Y@iteSdSr7Lq8Lf10e9WmOHn12XhNS7vOAhYrRz9LryrUwXy6Y@G7btr3Q3qPa84fFcXNqRPWiaCdraEGhwnuTqy83FHFN0zIHUO/n6gB/odWypl3/lo4BrYWSkFuawowsE8SHMNHjJitLwkYBmGCIbfmjJlAlmDix8iEsL5N5mMQceQ8QuETALMGCOlFBDXAWGDMkBNGP//EfvgB)

```java
a->{                      // Method with integer-array parameter and no return-type
  for(int z:a){           //  Loop over the array
    int s=1;              //   Sum-integer, starting at 1
    for(int y:a)          //   Inner loop over the array again
      s+=y%z%2;           //    Increase the sum by `y` modulo-`z` modulo-2
    System.out.print(" "  //   Print a space
      +(s<a.length)       //    + "true" if the sum is smaller than the length of the array
                          //      (this means there is at least one even)
      +(s<2));}}          //    + "true" if the sum is still 1
                          //      (this means all are even)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 42 bytes

```
a->[[!s=vecsum([x%y%2|x<-a]),s>#a-2]|y<-a]
```

Returns `[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]` instead of `0, 1, 2`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY39CoIwFMVf5WYICnfQPnQT0hcZ@2NERlAxtELBd193TRjs/M7OOQt@urNbiCP00bPB2sPcf6@X@fOs7FKupdiWM/Ouxnk4eibctiaMPoTHWnlgA4Tp/nqTLBIUMFa@rhGsBY4gwJEEiaCySh6CzKDwfzJoCjUnhJZn7hRlVdORK/e84RqBk9MJQ0LrfZ3TpGqpL2WLoEXq8L3TpL91ekIwdBtalakMztXxBw)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 82 bytes

```
#(for[R[(range(count %))]i R](set(for[j R :when(not= i j)](odd?(mod(% j)(% i))))))
```

A complete example with output conversion:

```
(def f #(for[R[(range(count %))]i R](set(for[j R :when(not= i j)](odd?(mod(% j)(% i)))))))
(->> [ 53, 47, 33, 87, 81, 3, 17] f
     (map {#{true} 1, #{false} 2, #{true false} 0}))
; (0 0 0 1 0 2 0)
```